# How do I make a numbered list?

Tags: python, list, random, numbered-list

I want to make a playlist generator, I have a list containing different songs and I want to generate a random numbered list from it containing only 10 items, and this is the code I tried:

```
import random

a = ['Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade',
     'Miracles in December - EXO',
     'All Too Well - Taylor Swift',
     'Gravity - Sara Bareilles',
     'Perfectly Perfect - Simple Plan',
     'Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance',
     'Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift',
     'Champagne - Taylor Swift',
     'Piece of Your Heart - Mayday Parade',
     'Blame It On The Rain - He Is We',
     'Sad Song - We The Kings',
     'Give It All - He Is We',
     ]

for x in range(1, 11):
    for y in random.sample(a, k=10):
        print(str(x) + y)
```

but I got this output:

```
1Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade
1All Too Well - Taylor Swift
1Blame It On The Rain - He Is We
1Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift
1Give It All - He Is We
1Miracles in December - EXO
1Perfectly Perfect - Simple Plan
1Gravity - Sara Bareilles
1Sad Song - We The Kings
1Piece of Your Heart - Mayday Parade
2All Too Well - Taylor Swift
2Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade
2Blame It On The Rain - He Is We
2Perfectly Perfect - Simple Plan
2Champagne - Taylor Swift
2Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift
2Piece of Your Heart - Mayday Parade
2Miracles in December - EXO
2Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance
2Give It All - He Is We
3Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade
3Gravity - Sara Bareilles
3Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance
3All Too Well - Taylor Swift
3Perfectly Perfect - Simple Plan
3Sad Song - We The Kings
3Champagne - Taylor Swift
3Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift
3Piece of Your Heart - Mayday Parade
3Give It All - He Is We
4Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift
4Blame It On The Rain - He Is We
4Piece of Your Heart - Mayday Parade
4Gravity - Sara Bareilles
4Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade
4Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance
4Miracles in December - EXO
4Sad Song - We The Kings
4Give It All - He Is We
4Perfectly Perfect - Simple Plan
5Gravity - Sara Bareilles
5Blame It On The Rain - He Is We
5Perfectly Perfect - Simple Plan
5Champagne - Taylor Swift
5Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift
5Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade
5Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance
5All Too Well - Taylor Swift
5Give It All - He Is We
5Miracles in December - EXO
6Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade
6Champagne - Taylor Swift
6Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift
6Miracles in December - EXO
6Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance
6Sad Song - We The Kings
6All Too Well - Taylor Swift
6Gravity - Sara Bareilles
6Give It All - He Is We
6Perfectly Perfect - Simple Plan
7Gravity - Sara Bareilles
7Sad Song - We The Kings
7Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift
7Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance
7Piece of Your Heart - Mayday Parade
7Blame It On The Rain - He Is We
7Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade
7Give It All - He Is We
7Champagne - Taylor Swift
7All Too Well - Taylor Swift
8Sad Song - We The Kings
8Gravity - Sara Bareilles
8Champagne - Taylor Swift
8Blame It On The Rain - He Is We
8Miracles in December - EXO
8Give It All - He Is We
8Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance
8Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade
8Piece of Your Heart - Mayday Parade
8Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift
9Gravity - Sara Bareilles
9Champagne - Taylor Swift
9Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade
9Blame It On The Rain - He Is We
9Piece of Your Heart - Mayday Parade
9Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift
9Sad Song - We The Kings
9Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance
9All Too Well - Taylor Swift
9Perfectly Perfect - Simple Plan
10Champagne - Taylor Swift
10Blame It On The Rain - He Is We
10Perfectly Perfect - Simple Plan
10Miracles in December - EXO
10Give It All - He Is We
10Piece of Your Heart - Mayday Parade
10Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift
10Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance
10Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade
10Sad Song - We The Kings
```

I want it to contain only 10 items, but I got way too many, could please help me
(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Similar canonical question: [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/522563/4518341)

Comment: Beside the point, but maybe you meant to write `print(x, y)`

Answer (score 4):

You're getting that output because you have an outer loop that iterates ten times, and an inner loop that also iterates ten times.  So you get ten `1`s, then ten `2`s, etc.

You don't need the outer `range()` loop.  Iterate only over the song choices, using `enumerate()` to get both the item position and the song title:

```
for position, title in enumerate(random.sample(a, k=10)):
    print(str(position) + title)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove your outer loop.

The nested loops will give you 10 x 10 lines of output.

Your call to `random.sample()` already produces the 10 (random) lines of output you need.

Also, use `enumerate` to iterate through & obtain the song index, starting at 1.

Try this:

```
import random

a = [
    'Bruised and Scarred - Mayday Parade',
    'Miracles in December - EXO',
    'All Too Well - Taylor Swift',
    'Gravity - Sara Bareilles',
    'Perfectly Perfect - Simple Plan',
    'Welcome To The Black Parade - My Chemical Romance',
    'Everything Has Changed - Taylor Swift',
    'Champagne - Taylor Swift',
    'Piece of Your Heart - Mayday Parade',
    'Blame It On The Rain - He Is We',
    'Sad Song - We The Kings',
    'Give It All - He Is We',
]

for i, y in enumerate(random.sample(a, k=10), 1):
    print(i, y)
```